# Jackson JSON: Filters declared within filters - how to ignore the child filter?

Tags: json, jackson

I'm getting an exception when a filter is declared within a filter. For example, given these classes (note that Parent has a Child member):

```
@JsonFilter("Parent")
public class Parent {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Child child;
    private String other1;
    private String other2;
    // other fields
}

@JsonFilter("Child")
public class Child {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    // other fields
}
```

When I generate JSON of class `Child` using filters I have no problems. But when I generate JSON of class `Parent` using filter this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

String[] ignorableFieldNames = { "other1", "other2" };

FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().
addFilter("Parent",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames));

mapper.filteredWriter(filters).writeValueAsString(object);
```

I get the error `No filter configured with id 'Child'`. I understand that since Child is declared in Parent and both have the `@JsonFilter` annotation, I get the error because I only use the Parent filter. But I need the annotation in both classes, as I also run the filter only on the Child class in a different program. What's the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer: you append `addFilter` two or more times for each annotated filter:

```
String[] ignorableFieldNames1 = { "other1", "other2" };
String[] ignorableFieldNames2 = { "other3", "other4" };

FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().     
addFilter("Parent",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames1))
addFilter("Child",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames2));
```